# take a subset of column from one df and paste into a row from another

Tags: pandas, row, transpose

df1

```
First Name    Last Name         
1. John       Smith              
2. Mary       Brohowski           
3. Aristidis  Papageorgopoulos   
4. James      Watss               
5. Kid        Red
```

df2

```
                  1.      2.      3.         4.    5.     6.    7. 
First Name        Marty   Sandy   Parry      May   Manny  Rudy  Wesley 
Last Name         Smith   Kevin   Brohowski  Dave  Garido Red   Redknap
```

how can i replace row  First Name 2:5 column in df2,  with index 1:5 from df1 Name column, so the out put will be :

df2

```
              1.      2.          3.                4.      5.     6.  7.
First Name    John    Mary        Aristidis         James   Kid   Rudy Wesle
Last Name     Smith   Brohowski   Papageorgopoulos  Watss   Red   Red  Redkn
```

Ive tried:

```
df1[['First Name']].combine_first(df2)
```

as i did with columns but this is not working

Comment: Isn't Wesley supposed to be in the expected output? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) like you want only trnspose values of first DataFrame by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
#if necessary
#df2 = df2.rename(columns=float)
#df1 = df1.rename(index=float)

df = df1.T.combine_first(df2)
print (df)
              1.0        2.0               3.0    4.0  5.0   6.0      7.0
First Name   John       Mary         Aristidis  James  Kid  Rudy   Wesley
Last Name   Smith  Brohowski  Papageorgopoulos  Watss  Red   Red  Redknap
```

First solution with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) - only first value in python is not `1`, but `0` so:

```
df2.iloc[0, 0:5] = df1.iloc[0:5, 0]
df2.iloc[1, 1:5] = df1.iloc[1:5, 1]
print (df2)
               1.         2.                3.     4.   5.    6.       7.
First Name   John       Mary         Aristidis  James  Kid  Rudy   Wesley
Last Name   Smith  Brohowski  Papageorgopoulos  Watss  Red   Red  Redknap
```

Comment: So you change when you see my solution?

Comment: no, it's not a copy, 
but I think you did something similar to my idea,are you sure that combine_first works here?

Comment: @ansev - yop, absolutely ;)

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that the type of the DataFrame 1 **index** matches the type of the dataframe 2 **columns**:

```
df2.columns=df2.columns.astype(float)
df1.index=df1.index.astype(float)
```

Then you only need [`DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) (notice that the parameter **overwrite** is **`True` by default**)+ [`DataFrame.transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
df2.update(df1.T)
print(df2)

             1.0        2.0               3.0    4.0  5.0   6.0      7.0
First Name   John       Mary         Aristidis  James  Kid  Rudy   Wesley
Last Name   Smith  Brohowski  Papageorgopoulos  Watss  Red   Red  Redknap
```

Comment: Ive tried doing it that way but i cant change the excel sheet as i have to leave it the same, is there another way? the was a reproduction -  the index of the column is number and the column names r string

Comment: Can i use iloc?

Comment: @Jienkles - sure, check another answer

Comment: Thank so much for solutions